# View form not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I have an Element in my CakePHP application that has some fields and a button.  I want to use this element to be placed in all my pages and when the user clicks the button, for it to go to the same controller and action.  The form in the Element works fine for the root page but when I'm on another page and click the button the function is never hit and the address bar will only have the controller/function appended to it.

Element:

```
<form id="login-user" action="Login/doSomething" method="post">

      <input id="edit-submit-button" class="form-submit" type="submit" value="Log in" name="op">   </input>
</form>
```

my controller is:

```
class LoginController  extends Controller{
    public  $helpers=array('Js'=>array('Jquery'), 'Session');

    public function index() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
    }

    function  doSomething(){            
        $this->redirect("/");

    }
}
```

I have this element in the Pages.ctp file and in a View.  When I click the button thats in the Pages.ctp file, the page gets redirected to localhost/myApp/Login/doSomething and the function get hit just fine.  But if the element is in a view (localhost/myApp/somePage/view) and the user clicks the form button, the page will only reload and have "Login/doSomething" appended to the end of the address but never hit the function.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

1) you should try to use the FormHelper instead of writing it manually

2) you should at very least build the URL with CakePHP Helper or something

3) your link is relative - add a `/` before it and it would probably work - if it still doesn't, then your link is simply wrong.

**Example:**

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
    'url' => array(
        'controller'=>'users',
        'action'=>'login'
    ),
    'id' => 'login-user'
));
//...
```

Comment: Do you mean add "/" to the action, like 'action="/Login/doSomething"'?  If so, I have tried this and I just get a 404 error.  I would rather not do this with a form helper.  How would I build the URL with a helper?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I wanted to keep the regular forms and not use a form helper for other reasons but this lead me to a solution.  I just prepended the action with the name of the app (ie:  <form id="login-user" action="/myApp/Login/doSomething" method="post">)

Comment: @jason - If doing that works, then there's an issue with your setup.  That shouldn't work.  Try setting the action using the HtmlHelper:  `action="<?php echo echo $this->Html->url(array("controller" => "posts", "action" => "view")); ?>"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your action to include the Controller + Action

Example you have :

```
<form id="login-user" action="Login/doSomething" method="post">
```

If Login is your controller it should be :

```
<form id="login-user" action="/Login/doSomething" method="post">
```

But if your following MVC; User should be your Controller and Login should be your method, also you if your using CakePHP it's best to follow the convention and use the HTML Helper it Provides, Your above code :

```
<form id="login-user" action="Login/doSomething" method="post">

  <input id="edit-submit-button" class="form-submit" type="submit" value="Log in" name="op">   </input>
</form>
```

Should be :

```
 <?php
   echo $this->Form->create('User', array('id'=>'login-user', 'url'=>'/user/login'));
   echo $this->Form->submit('Log In', array('class'=>'form-submit', 'id'=>'edit-submit-button'));
   echo $this->Form->end();
 ?>
```

When creating your Controllers, think to yourself.... Is this a main entity and will it need multiple methods...

Such as....I need the user to login, in CakePHP....The User should be the Controller with a method "login"

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I wanted to keep the regular forms and not use a form helper for other reasons but this lead me to a solution.  I just prepended the action with the name of the app (ie:  <form id="login-user" action="/myApp/Login/doSomething" method="post">)